# SharePoint 2019 Server APIs

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I am merging 2 legacy microsoft applications in modernization project. One is CMS site running on SharePoint 2013 and other is .NET 2.0 web application having transactional UI functionality. I am in favor of a common JavaScript UI portal (ReactJS) and access the backend (including SharePoint 2019) through REST APIs sitting behind an API Gateway. Alternate solution is use SharePoint Framework (SPFx) but then frontend will become tightly coupled with SharePoint and also require converting to SAML 1.1 for authentication. With first approach, my architecture will be simpler and flexible to upgrade UI in future.

My question is - can I use on-premise SharePoint 2019 server just as CMS through its APIs? If yes, are there reference architecture available? Any guidance will be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, so I think you have to check [Content Management Interoperability Services](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis/#whats-content-management-interoperability-services-cmis) that supported in SharePoint 2019.

> Content Management Interoperability Service is a web service standard that allows different content management systems to inter-operate seamlessly over the Internet.

For more details, please check **[how to Configure CMIS in SharePoint 2016 and SharePoint 2019](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis/)**

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I am looking to use SharePoint REST APIs as described in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

Comment: or something like this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint